# React Router 4 Regular Expression In Path Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

I have a React app using React Router 4 with the following route that runs on my filter page and it is complete without any query strings:

```
https://example.com/products/dept/electronics/cat/sterio/type/home-theatre/sort/high-to-low/price/200-800/size/large/color/red/brand/sony/store/sony
```

The requirement is that each part is a variable and optional and can be in no particular order except for `/products`

Now I manage to match the domain with the following regular expression route but the values of the variables are undefined:

```
path: "/products(/dept/:catSlug)?(/cat/:subCatSlug)?(/type/:childSubCatSlug)?(/sort/:sorting)?(/price/:price)?(/size/:size)?(/color/:color)?(/brand/:brands)?(/store/:stores)?"
```

It also matches with the following and get the values, but then I need them in a specific order and I'll end up making hundereds of routes to match each permutation:

```
path: "/products/dept/:catSlug?/cat/:subCatSlug?/type/:childSubCatSlug?...."
```

Is there anyway around this in React Router 4

Comment: Is there a reason to not use query parameters? Anyway, I'd match only the `products/` path with react router and do the matching by hand for the rest of the params

Comment: @Axnyff It's already built that way, I think the plan was to index all the pages...

Could you elaborate on matching by hand?